# Search button out of div

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

here is example of my problem. You can see that clickable search button places litle bit higher than search field.

[image]

**HTML**

```
 <div class="search_menu">             
    <%= form_tag search_index_path, :method => 'get' do %>                                                          
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :placeholder=> (I18n.t 'placeholder') %>                           
            <%= image_submit_tag ('search_button_main.png'),:title=> (I18n.t 'search_now')  %>                      

    <%end%>     
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.search_menu {
display:block;
float:right;
width:200px;
height:30px;
}
```

I tried to

```
position:relative;
top:10px;
```

For either search field or button but still every time search button is up in air.
What could cause this kind of problem?

Comment: i don't think whatever you've labelled as **HTML** is **HTML**. please provide proper HTML or a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something that replicates the issue...

Comment: @TJ The code labeled “HTML” is ERB, the default templating language of Rails. It is HTML with embedded Ruby within `<% %>` and `<%= %>` tags. The embedded Ruby generates HTML, like [`image_submit_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/image_submit_tag) generating an `<input type="image">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to align the input field with image. Here is the one of the most easiest method by giving `vertical-align:bottom` to image.

```
.search_menu img{vertical-align:bottom; display:block;}
```

**Update**:

After seeing the code its clear that instead of image an `input type=image` is in used. so I've changed a code a little bit. Check the latest **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/rixipile/1/edit)**.

.`search_menu input[type="image"]{vertical-align:bottom; display:inline-block;}`

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to take a guess since the access to the rendered HTML is limited. If I interpreted correctly I saw you have an image and probably its alignment is not correct. Try something like this:

```
.search_menu img{
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```